# why can't call a function in A class but can call it in B class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to call updateGold() in ShowMoney class but failed.

If success,it should show money.gold in console, but don't show anything.

And golText.text don't update.

Even I change to Debug.Log("OK") in updateGold(),don't show anything in console.

But when I call updateGold() in Money class, it success. What the difference?

=========================================================

```
//Prop.cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Prop : MonoBehaviour,IPointerClickHandler
{
    public int goldPrice;
    public int diamondPrice;
    public int propID;

    public GameObject goldError;
    public GameObject diamondError;
    public GameObject purchasePanel;

    //check if purchased when back to this Level
    void Awake()
    {
        if(Bag.propIsPurchased[propID]==true)
        {
            alreadySold();
        }
    }

    //show purchase panel and add delegate
    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        purchasePanel.SetActive(true);
        ConfirmPurchase.ensureOperation += this.purchase;
        CancelPurchase.cancelOperation += this.cancel;
    }

    public void purchase()
    {
        if (goldPrice>0)
        {
            if(goldPrice > Money.gold)
            {
                goldError.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                Money.payGold(goldPrice);
                ShowMoney.updateGold();//problem here
                Bag.addProp(propID);
                alreadySold();
            }
        }
        //...       
    }
//...

//ShowMoney.cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShowMoney : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject goldText;
    public GameObject diamondText;

    public static Text golText;
    public static Text diaText;

    void Awake()
   {
        golText = goldText.GetComponent<Text>();
        diaText = diamondText.GetComponent<Text>();
        updateGold();
        updateDiamond();
    }

    public static void updateGold()
    {
        Debug.Log(Money.gold);
        golText.text = Money.gold.ToString();
    } 

    public static void updateDiamond()
    {       
        diaText.text = Money.diamond.ToString();
    }
}

//Money.cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Money: MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int gold = 100;
    public static int diamond = 20;

    public static Money instance;
    void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }   

    public static void earnGold(int gol)
    {
        gold += gol;
    }

    public static void earnDiamond(int dia)
    {
        diamond += dia;
    }

    public static void payGold(int gol)
    {
        gold -= gol;
        //ShowMoney.updateGold();//can work here
    }

    public static void payDiamond(int dia)
    {
        diamond -= dia; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `can't call it here` means what are you getting any error?

Comment: @un-lucky no error, just no reaction. If it works ,it should show money.gold first in console, but nothing happens. And golText.text don't update.

Comment: What does `but failed` mean? How did it fail?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt no reaction. If it works ,it should show money.gold in console, but nothing happens. And golText.text don't update

Comment: What message do you get? Also please post the 2nd class definition

Comment: @ChenxingZheng I'm not the only one who needs to know this information. Include it in your question.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Thanks for you kindly remind:-)

Comment: Just to make sure, the `else` part is actually executed? Like `Money.payGold`, `Bag.addProp` and `alreadySold` are executed?

Comment: @GunnarB.Yes, Money.payGold, Bag.addProp and alreadySold are all executed.

Comment: @ChenxingZheng Can you add Debug messages in your Awake method so you know if the method is actually executed?

Comment: @ChenxingZheng Because I actually copied the two methods Money.cs and ShowMoney.cs for testing and they worked perfectly.

Comment: @Rafiwui Thanks for your kindly help! I find the problem. There is a similar script on the component instead of Prop......

Answer (score 0):

Define your method Before Void and still Problem not solved then Make Protected Method that only accessible by its next method .

```js
public static void updateGold()
{
    Debug.Log(Money.gold);
    golText.text = Money.gold.ToString();
} 

public static void updateDiamond()
{       
    diaText.text = Money.diamond.ToString();
}

public void Awake()
{
    golText = goldText.GetComponent<Text>();
    diaText = diamondText.GetComponent<Text>();
    updateGold();
    updateDiamond();
}
```

Comment: 1.make Awake() public? 2.define updateGold() before Awake()? I try these but still get the same result